# Unidentified mistake in usage of Stack

Tags: c, stack, binary-tree

I am trying to implement BinaryTree using pointers and than I have to create a new binary tree from postfix expression (and print it) using Stack.

The function "create" should be doing that but every time it gets to StTop or StPop the program stops working.

My function gets string and than for every char c does as follows:
If c is a letter than it creates a binary tree whose root is c and its children are NULL, and puts it on top of Stack "niz".

Else using Stack it pops out last and second to last value from the Stack and creates new tree where char c is the root, last value is the right child, second to last is the left child and puts it back on top of the Stack.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Every hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define LAMBDA NULL
#define MAXLENGHT 10000

typedef char labeltype;

typedef struct celltag{
    labeltype label;
    struct celltag *leftchild;
    struct celltag *rightchild;
} celltype;

typedef celltype *node; //ovo ti je cvor
typedef celltype *BinaryTree;


void BiMakeNull(BinaryTree *Tp)
{
    *Tp=NULL;
}

int BiEmpty(BinaryTree T)
{
    if(T==NULL) return 0;
    return 1;
}

void BiCreate(labeltype l, BinaryTree TL, BinaryTree TR, BinaryTree *Tp)
{
    (*Tp)=(celltype*)malloc(sizeof(celltype));
    (*Tp)->label= l;
    (*Tp)->leftchild=TL;
    (*Tp)->leftchild=TR;
}

void BiLeftSubtree(BinaryTree T, BinaryTree *TLp)
{
    (*TLp)=T->leftchild;
}

void BiRightSubtree(BinaryTree T, BinaryTree *TRp)
{
    (*TRp)=T->rightchild;
}

node BiInsertLeftChild(labeltype l, node i, BinaryTree *Tp)
{
    if(i==NULL) exit(1);
    if(i->leftchild != NULL) exit(2);

    i->leftchild->label=l;
    i->leftchild->leftchild=NULL;
    i->leftchild->rightchild=NULL;

    return i->leftchild;
}

 node BiInsertRightChild(labeltype l, node i, BinaryTree *Tp)
 {
    if(i==NULL) exit(1);
    if(i->rightchild != NULL) exit(2);

    i->rightchild->label=l;
    i->rightchild->rightchild=NULL;
    i->rightchild->rightchild=NULL;

    return i->rightchild;
 }

 void BiDelete(node i, BinaryTree *Tp)
 {
     if(i==NULL) exit(3);
     if(i->leftchild!=NULL || i->rightchild!= NULL) exit(4);

     i=NULL;
 }

 node BiRoot(BinaryTree T)
 {
     if(T==NULL) return LAMBDA;
     return T;
 }

 node BiLeftChild(node i, BinaryTree T)
 {
     if(i==NULL) exit(5);
     if(i->leftchild==NULL) return LAMBDA;
     return i->leftchild;
 }

 node BiRightChild(node i, BinaryTree T)
 {
     if(i==NULL) exit(5);
     if(i->rightchild==NULL) return LAMBDA;
     return i->rightchild;
 }

 node nadiRoditelja(node i, node root)
 {
     if(root->leftchild==i || root->rightchild==i) return root;

     if(root->leftchild!=NULL) {nadiRoditelja(i, root->leftchild);}
     if(root->rightchild!=NULL) {nadiRoditelja(i, root->rightchild);}

 }

 node BiParent(node i, BinaryTree T)
 {
     if(i==NULL) exit(6);
     if(i==T) return LAMBDA;

     node parent;
     parent=nadiRoditelja(i, BiRoot(T));
     return parent;
 }

 labeltype BiLabel(node i, BinaryTree T)
 {
     if(i==NULL) exit(7);
     return i->label;
 }

void BiChangeLabel(labeltype l, node i, BinaryTree *Tp)
{
    if(i==NULL) exit(8);
    i->label=l;
}


//implementacija stoga pomocu polja 


typedef struct {
    int top;
    BinaryTree elementi[MAXLENGHT];
} Stack;


void StMakeNull(Stack *St)
{
    St->top=MAXLENGHT;
}

int StEmpty(Stack S)
{
    if(S.top>=MAXLENGHT) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void StPush(BinaryTree x, Stack *Sp)
{
    if(Sp->top==0) exit(101);
    else{
        Sp->top--;
        Sp->elementi[Sp->top]=x;
    }
}

void StPop(Stack *Sp)
{
    if(StEmpty(*Sp)){exit(212);}
    else{
            Sp->top++;
    }

}

BinaryTree StTop(Stack S)
{
    if(StEmpty(S)) {exit(202);}
    else{
        return (S.elementi[S.top]);
    }
}





void Postorder(node i, BinaryTree T)
{
    if(i)
    {
        Postorder(BiLeftChild(i,T), T);
        Postorder(BiRightChild(i, T), T);
        printf(" %c", BiLabel(i, T));
    }
}

void printajdrvo(BinaryTree T, node root)
{
    printf(" %c ", BiLabel(root, T));
    if(BiLabel(BiLeftChild(root, T), T)== 0) {printf(" NULL ");return;}
    else{printf(" %c ", BiLabel(BiLeftChild(root, T), T) );}

    if(BiLabel(BiRightChild(root, T), T)== 0) {printf(" NULL\n"); return;}
    else{printf(" %c\n", BiLabel(BiRightChild(root, T), T) );}

    printajdrvo(T, BiLeftChild(root, T));
    printajdrvo(T, BiRightChild(root, T));

}

BinaryTree create(char string[100])
{
    Stack niz;
    StMakeNull(&niz);
    BinaryTree pom, poml, pomr;
    BiMakeNull(&pom);
    BiMakeNull(&poml);
    BiMakeNull(&pomr);
    BinaryTree newroot;

    int i=0;
    while(string[i]!='\0')
    {
        BiCreate(string[i], poml, pomr, &pom);



        if(string[i]>='A' && string[i]<='z')
        {
            StPush(pom, &niz);
        }
        else{

            BinaryTree l,d;
            BiMakeNull(&l);
            BiMakeNull(&d);
            BiMakeNull(&newroot);
            newroot=pom;
            
            d=StTop(niz);

            StPop(&niz);

            l=StTop(niz);

            StPop(&niz);

            BiCreate(string[i],l,d,&newroot);
            StPush(newroot, &niz);

        }
        BiMakeNull(&pom);
      i++;
    }
    return newroot;
}

int main()
{

    char string[100];
    printf("Enter postfix: \n");
    scanf(" %s", string);
    BinaryTree T;
    BiMakeNull(&T);
    T = create(string);
    printajdrvo(T, BiRoot(T));
    Postorder(BiRoot(T), T);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input you are using to test? What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: Hi, my input is ABCE^D|&|
 And output:
| A &
A NULL NULL
& B |
B NULL NULL
| ^ D
^ C E
C NULL NULL
E NULL NULL
D NULL NULL

Comment: There are a lot of warnings in this code. You might work on fixing those. https://godbolt.org/z/E4aY6Ebxh

Comment: My course professor said that our functions must have those arguments, but I think I fixed the other mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

printajdrvo never exits, it will recurse forever

vs says

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4717   'printajdrvo': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow   ConsoleApplication3 C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp 205
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that nadiRoditelja (find parent) does return root. I will try to fix print

Comment: The complete first line of that function is if(root->leftchild==i || root->rightchild==i) return root;

Comment: @Mari123 you are correct, my bad. But the first error is the really serious one, infinite recirsion

Comment: The problem with `nadiRoditelja` is it returns nothing from the recursion. You need to capture the return value of the recursive call and return that. There also needs to be a catchall `return NULL;` for when the children are NULL and the value was not found.